# Unwanted white space on right site (small screen only)

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I have a responsive site I am working on. It has a gap of white space on the right side of the screen at screen sizes roughly below 767px. This is the point it goes to the "mobile" layout. I had the same issue on the desktop size and fixed it by setting the footer to 99% width and it fixed the issue on the larger screen sizes. I tried playing with the footer width for the mobile size, but with no luck.

I have not idea what is causing this white space on the right side of the screen on smaller viewports. I tried the inspect tool in the console, but I couldn't find the problem.

I would post code, but seeing as I can't track the problem down, I wouldn't know what to post.

URL of page: http://sevenclanscasino.designangler.com/warroad/warroad-home

Comment: It seems happening because of Flex slider - http://prntscr.com/3404a1

Comment: @Nix Any Ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: hmm, I revisited, flex's div already has overflow set to hidden. That can't cause it. Did you try @aloisdg's solution of margin? Try adding following to end of your style.css: `.row { margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0; }`

Comment: Alternatively, just change class "row" inside footer tag to another class and set rules for new class. To me it seems that's the culprit -  http://prntscr.com/340amw

Comment: @Nix, I changed the row class on the footer and that did seem to do it. It doesn't look like it really needs to use the Bootstrap row class to be functional so I am just going to get rid of it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, structure is very important when you build the websites. It's a good practice to test on various viewports and browsers to eliminate bugs.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone with a similar issue and struggling by hovering over elements in devtools, I came across this trick [on another forum.](https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/adoptly-white-space-along-the-entire-right-side-of-page/27469/7)

`* { border: 1px solid red !important; }`

This very very helpfully shows you all the boundaries in your project. In my case it was a grid overflowing its parent. Enjoy!

Comment: really helpful for debugging

Comment: Life saving comment!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change some elements into your css.

```
.row { margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; }
header #top-nav-container #top-nav { width: 100%; }
header #top-nav-container #top-nav { margin-left: 0; }
```

another way (but please dont do that) :

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: could you please explain the reason for the first solution? I am not sure how my top navigation would affect this. When I look at it in the inspector, it does not even come close to the edges of the layout. Thanks.

Comment: Well, your .row class go outside because of the negative margin. For #top-nav-container resize your windows to 500px;.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. Thank you though.

Comment: well it remove the whitespace in my screen. Maybe I am forgetting something.

Answer (score 0):

When working on a responsive website, you should always set width values in % rather than px. So try setting `with:100%`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I should set what to %? I have all the widths in percent.